# Issue with event timing. Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I am having trouble with running code only when a toolbar button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', `#toolbar-markupTool`, function(e) {
        console.log('hi');
});
```

This works with anything except the markupTool icon... lucky me! I think this is due to there being an event that hide the toolbar that is handled by the markups gui extension. When the icon is clicked, the toolbar gets hidden, so my guess is that my event doesn't get executed because the element is hidden now.

The reason why I absolutely need to do it this way because I have an element that captures a screenshot that must absolutely only be shown when markups mode is activated. Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [EXTENSION_ACTIVATED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#extension-activated-event) filtering by extensionId ("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui") or [TOOL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#tool-change-event) filtering by toolName("markups.core").